# Does the sentence "Do you find your partner through your heart or brain?" express the following meaning?

Tags: expression-choice

Here is the meaning behind the question which I want to ask people:

Ok, so how do you choose the one you love? There are two types of people. The first type of people use their feelings or emotions or heart to find love. For example, you see a girl and your emotion tells you that you want to date her and you don't care whether she is rich or poor.

On the other hand, the second type of people use their judgement or logic to find love. For example, you see a girl wearing expensive clothes or driving an expensive car, etc. So you want to date her just because she is rich. You don't use your emotion or feeling when dating her at all. Or maybe she is not rich but she has something you are looking for.

Are you the first or second type of person as mentioned above?

So, to be able to find out which type of person you are, I want to ask this question:

> Do you find your partner through your heart or brain?

Is phrasing it that way clear enough to convey my idea to people?

Comment: It's unclear to the extent that *love*, by definition, is an emotion (or more rarely refers to rarely the sex act). That is, it is not possible to *love* without your heart. Maybe you want to say "*date*" or "*seek a partner*", or some other synonym which makes your question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual turn of phrase which contrasts the metaphysical *heart* is "using your head or your heart", because of the alliteration, and possibly because of the similar spelling.

Note the order: in most cases, the heart is the best decider, so it comes last. In asking your question

> Do you find your partner through your head or your heart?

you would need to set the scenes in that order.